# the namespace prefix "utilities" is not defined

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, binding

I am fairly new to WPFs... I was trying to bind a validation to a text box in WPF.

Here is my text box in the xaml:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Source="{x:Static r:Settings.Default}" Path="ServerIP" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <utilities:PingValidationRule />
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Here is my validation class:

```
    public class PingValidationRule : ValidationRule
    { 
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            ...
            if (ipCorrect) return new ValidationResult(true, null);
            else return new ValidationResult(false, "It's not an IP");
        }
    }
```

With this I have the following error:

> Error     The namespace prefix "utilities" is not defined.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: It is not defined because you did not define it. Look at the top of your XAML file, all the stuff like `xmlns:foobar="clr-namespace:Foo.Bar"`. You need to define it there.

Comment: Yeah, it was that. Now I should be able to put a break in my method and when debuging it should stop there right?

Comment: Yes, I think it ought to, from what I can see there -- try it though.

Comment: It doesn't stop, I just press a button and the text box isn't validate.

Comment: If you add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"` to the `Binding` tag, what do you see in the Output pane in VS when you type in the textbox?

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to do it, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not defined because you did not define it. Look at the top of your XAML file, all the stuff like `xmlns:foobar="clr-namespace:Foo.Bar"`. You need to define it there.